# What is the general rule $\imath^n$, $n \in N$ and how to get it?

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the general rule for $i^n$, $n \in N$ and how do you get it?

Comment: Just compute the first few values (say 5 or maybe 9), and you'll see.

Comment: What happens when you multiply a complex number $z$ by $i$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as everyone has already told you, summary:
$$i^{4k}=1$$ $$i^{4k+1}=i$$ $$i^{4k+2}=-1$$ $$i^{4k+3}=-i$$. Here $k$ is a non-negative integer.

Answer (score 1):

you can compute some examples: $$i^1=i$$, $$i^2=-1$$, $$i^3 =-i$$ $$i^4=1$$ $$i^5=i$$, $$i^6=-1$$, $$i^7=-i$$ $$i^8=1$$ and so one.